# Spring авторизация

Tags: java, spring

Хочу сделать авторизацию в Spring используя hibernate, 
Выходит ошибка
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User where username=?

Созданы классы

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public User findByUserName(String username) {

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from User where username=?")
            .setParameter(0, username)
            .list();

    System.out.println(users.size());

    if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

MyUserDetailService

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        return userDao.findByUserName(username);
    }
}
```

В data.xml прописал бин

```
<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="kz.tanikin.springtest.service.MyUserDetailsService" />
```

а в security.xml

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
</authentication-manager>
```

User использую стандартный import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

в чем может быть дело?

создал две таблицы users и authority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все сконфигурировано корректно, то я бы рекомендовал использовать Criteria API. Будет что-то вроде.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
users = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(User.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("username",username))
        .list();
```

**UPD** если User - объект из внешней либы, то меппинг работать не будет.
Тогда бы рекомендовал попробовать sql query, должно получиться что-то вроде

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
users = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createSqlQuery("select * from User where username=?")
        .setParameter(0, username)
        .addEntity(User.class)
        .list();
```

Вместо `select *` лучше написать `select username ...`, т.е. конкретный набор колонок в соответствии со свойствами объекта User.

**UPD2** Но правильным вариантом будет все же создать свой класс User с описанием меппингов и прочего, а потом его уже преобразовывать в спринговый User `new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), ...`

Comment: Первые два способа не работают, даже нет таких метовов, createCriteria, и createSqlQuery

Comment: Что-то странно. Сейчас под рукой нет своих проектов, чтобы точно проверить еще раз.

Но тем не менее, в любом случае я крайне рекомендую создать свою сущность (класс User), которая будет мепиться на таблицу БД. А дальше уже на ее основе создавать объекта класс User (спринговый).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка однозначно следует из сообщения Exception: вы забыли написать Hibernate, что есть такая сущность `User`, - сделать это можно через свойство `annotatedClasses`. 
В принципе, Hibernate попытается замапить имплементацию `User` из Spring Security, если вы ее укажете в качестве entity в маппинге. Но вы не сможете автоматически сгенерировать таблицу по этой сущности.